# Haskell - How do filter and head work in combination with where?

Tags: haskell

Here's the code.

```
largestDivisible :: (Integral a) => a  
largestDivisible = head (filter p [100000,99999..])  
    where p x = x `mod` 3829 == 0
```

I am little bit confused. What is p in this case? Also, I do not understand the where expression in this particular example, because we got two expressions with p and x on the left side and we have one alignment, which is actually a boolean.

I would appreciate, if someone could explain me the above code.

Comment: So, that means for the first case:
p 100000

Then it evaluates p. It returns true for p if 100000 is divisible by 3829. Right?

Comment: Yes, but then you need to consider what `filter` does in that case. Once you understand what `filter` does when `p` returns `True` and what `filter` does when `p` returns `False`, you can tell what `head` does.

Comment: @SassaNF: filter is type of (a -> Boolean) -> [a] -> [a]. In that case it returns false for 100000. So the first argument is false, that's why 100000 is not put in the new constructed list. Is it something like this?

Comment: yes, correct. Then think what will appear in the list. Then also think whether it will matter what the next elements are.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a function, which accepts an argument `x` and returns `True` only if x is divisible by 3829. You can use `where` to define local functions just like you define local "values", using the same `f x = y` syntax you use to define top-level functions.

Comment: Does the second p have anything to do with the first p?

Comment: E.g. filter >5 [4,2,3,8,7] would return [8,7]. So in this case, the first p would be equivalent to the >5. But in the example above, what is p there?

Comment: Is the list not infinite? Is that not a problem?
First is 'filter' applied. But if the list is infinite, 'filter' will never finish its work?

Comment: @user2965601 You can `filter` infinite lists, so long as you only use no more elements than can be returned by that filter.  It may sound confusing, so here's an example.  The function `head $ filter even [1..]` will return because `filter even [1..]` returns `[2,4..]`, then `head` takes the first element, but `length $ filter even [1..]` won't ever finish computing because filtering an infinite list will always return an "infinite" list.  I put "infinite" in quotes because it's in the sense that the compiler thinks it keeps going, not whether mathematics says it would keep going.

Comment: @user2965601 The compiler can only be so smart.  If you said `filter (<= 4) [1..]`, you may know intuitively that the result should be `[1,2,3,4]`, but the compiler thinks it has to check every element in the list `[1..]` just to be sure.  It isn't equipped the knowledge that the remainder of the list is all greater than 4, just that there are more elements to check.  For all it knows, the 9028309823498th element is 1, for whatever reason, so it has to compute every element just to be sure.  But again, this is only if you ask for anything beyond the 5th element of `filter (<= 4) [1..]`.

Comment: @user2965601: The second `p` is the definition of the function, and the first `p` is a usage of it.